# How to fix an icon that is not showing (FontAwesome)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, icons, font-awesome

The icon i want to display is not showing up.

I installed FontAwesome like indicated in this page: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs

I also reinstalled it.

```vue
<font-awesome-icon 
    icon="spinner" 
    class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw">
</font-awesome-icon>

<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
```

The following error message is displayed:

> Could not find one or more icon(s) {prefix: "fas", iconName: "spinner"}

No icon is shown.

Comment: check first are you import the 'fontawesome-free-solid' and use in library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly likely you're not adding the icon into the `library` from the `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` package for use by the component.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faSpinner } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon);

library.add(faSpinner);
```

Once you do that, there is no need to specify the classes anymore. So if you need a spinner icon that [spins](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/animating-icons), is [3x](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons) as large and has [fixed-width](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons) — you should do the following instead.

```vue
<font-awesome-icon 
  icon="spinner" 
  size="3x" 
  spin fixed-width>
</font-awesome-icon>
```

---

**Reference**:

https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#basic

Comment: Yes, that helped. I included the desired icon in the main.js and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped :)